# npm show "NPM ELF : not found error" in WSL

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i got error when running npm, i've allready try to reinstall with

`sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm -y && sudo apt-get install nodejs npm -y`

this problem still exist

```
/usr/bin/node: 1: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/node: 2: : not found
/usr/bin/node: 4: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

im using Ubuntu WSL

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Linux localhost 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

npm -v command

```
npm -v
-bash: /usr/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This was an issue for me on Windows 10, using WSL2 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The other solutions in this post did not help, and I was unwilling to downgrade to Ubuntu 20. Instead, I managed to fix it by removing all node-related packages with apt and then installing node via nvm as per [this guide by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl).

So to remove the packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm
```

Then install nvm...

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

**Restart the terminal.** Then, make sure nvm is installed:

```
nvm --version
```

Finally, use nvm to install the latest version of node and npm:

```
nvm install node
```

Check to make sure node and npm are installed:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me on Windows Linux subsystem.  Thank you!

Comment: Same issue on Win10 + WSL2@Ubuntu - worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the solution to work, which was given here.

A different solution propossed from [the same source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8151) which itself linked to [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) worked for me:

I first removed *node* and *npm* completly (To be precise all packages with the name in it, but I am not sure this is necessary). Then I used the give install command:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This is for Ubuntu and node version 18, but you can find other operating systems and versions as well ([look here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall)).

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with WSL Ubuntu 22 Jammy and 8.5.1 package.
You may have luck installing a different package version, but I had issues with this.
Installed WSL Ubuntu 20 with 6.14.4, issue was gone.

Comment: I fixed this issue, see my answer!