# NPM is really slow performing simple tasks

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04

Everything I do with NPM takes several minutes; especially `npm install`, even if I already have all the packages installed. I first thought the problem is that the old code I am working with just takes longer to update (because last time an older npm version was used) but the problem percists even if I repeat the process.

My system and other Information:

- Windows 11 PC
- [Ubuntu 18.04.5 VM from the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PNKSF5ZN4SW)
- VS Code.
- npm version 8.19.2
- node version 16.17.0
- From my package-lock.json file: "lockfileVersion": 2
- I usally have 5 to 10 dependecies listed in my package file
- My internet speed is around 25 MB/s

What I tried so far with no luck:

- A newer Version of Ubuntu
- Using `http` instead of `https` *a la*:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
```

as was suggested in ['npm install' extremely slow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395211/npm-install-extremely-slow-on-windows).
It seems to me it still tries to connect to the `https` address (at least that's what it looks like if I use `npm install --verbose` to show more feedback).

- Reinstalling Node and NPM through other means as it was suggested in [Why is "npm install" really slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524903/why-is-npm-install-really-slow)

No matter what I still sit here, wasting ages waiting for my npm install.

Comment: Which version of node and npm are you using? Does your package have a shrinkwrap or lock file? If so, what is the version of the file? (eg: `"lockfileVersion": 2,`) And finally, how many packages are you downloading with `npm install` and what's your internet connection speed?

Comment: It can also depend on hardware specs

Comment: @ant 
npm version 8.19.2, 
node version 16.17.0, 
from my package-lock.json file: "lockfileVersion": 2, 
I usally have 5 to 10 dependecies listed in my package file,
My speed is around 25 MB/s

Comment: Have you tried installing Node.js/npm natively on Windows to see if that speeds things up?

Comment: I started with that using the Windows shell but then certain packages would have no compatibility with windows. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found a solution. I just did not now to ask the right question.

The problem was that I was using WSL version 2 and my files are in C: and not the Ubuntu folders. A fix that worked for me was moving to WSL version 1.

[More details can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/15205628)

If you're also switching to WSL version 1 and are having problems with node or npm, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73673804/npm-show-npm-elf-not-found-error-in-wsl).