# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted errno:-1

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, npx

I wanted to make a react native app so I was following this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2UBjN5ER4s
React Website Tutorial. I am primarily on windows I wanted my computer to accept commands just like Brian's.
So I figured out a way
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzgwDbe7foQ
Using Corry's method on installing the Ubuntu app I also installed a couple of things listed below and tried running the command npx create-react-app

```
added 1394 packages in 5m

213 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
node:internal/fs/utils:348
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/mnt/c/Users/user/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/cra-template/template/README.md' -> '/mnt/c/Users/user/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/README.md'
    at Object.copyFileSync (node:fs:2866:3)
    at copyFile (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:73:6)
    at onFile (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:59:25)
    at getStats (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:51:44)
    at startCopy (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:41:10)
    at copyDirItem (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:125:10)
    at /mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:118:39
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at copyDir (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:118:23)
    at onDir (/mnt/c/Users/moham/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:108:10) {
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: '/mnt/c/Users/user/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/node_modules/cra-template/template/README.md',
  dest: '/mnt/c/Users/user/Visual Studio Code Projects/website/react-website/README.md'
}

Node.js v18.12.1

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
```

I just wanted to execute commands just like Brian's through windows rather than purchasing a mac or etc.

I installed the js nodes and npm via command:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

which I got from here: [npm show "NPM ELF : not found error" in WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73673804/npm-show-npm-elf-not-found-error-in-wsl)

I also wanted to upvote or commented but since I "just" joined I couldn't.

thank you for any help I am going to remove everything start from scratch in the mean time

I also installed g -g++ something along those lines in order to get the npm working I am beginner just getting started.

Again thank you for reading and helping.

(If I figured it out I will update this post whenever possible)

If this helps out anybody else in the future cheers.

Answer (score 0):

## Follow the mentioned steps

1. Use the MSI installer from the nodejs [download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Run the command mentioned below using CMD as administrator

```bash
npm install -g node-gyp
```

3. Now run the react related commands

Note: The issue is that your terminal/cmd does not have write permission, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you for help now its asking where is node js installed

Node.js v18.12.1
Could not determine Node.js install directory

Comment: node:net:397
    err = this._handle.open(fd);
                       ^
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (node:net:397:24)
    at createWritableStdioStream (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:78:18)
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:148:12)
    at console.get (node:internal/console/constructor:210:42)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:338:50)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:377:61)
    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:90:5)

Comment: Need to see some code related to the issue

Comment: Hey update here ,I just used VS Code to make the react-project I was thinking of making thanks for the help. I also tried to install MAC OS via a VM using Oracle VM VirtualBox that didn't go so well either so

Comment: I guess a live session is required to see whats going on